# Is it possible to force web server to retrieve embeded video content?

Tags: video, web, youtube, embed

I'd like to build a website where I can embed videos from youtube.com/vimeo.com and maybe others. The problem is that these sites are blocked in the place I live in, so I can not just put the embed code in the web pages. I'm thinking to buy a web hosting or VPS that have access to these video sites, build a website, and when users view a page with embedded videos, my web server or whatever applications can retrieve the video content and play to the users that don't have direct access to youtube/vimeo etc.

Is it possible at all?

It doesn't matter as to which language to use to implement it, but preferably Python or PHP.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a firefox flash downloader addon, and look at the source. It should give you an idea of what of how the process works and then you can go from there.

http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/tip-how-to-unpack-xpi-files/